# apt install doesn't install python3.6

Tags: apt, python3

For some reason `sudo apt install python3.6` doesn't install anything, even after updating and adding repos from which it should pull from.

```bsh
$ sudo apt install python3.6

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3.6-2to3' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.6-stdlib' for regex 'python3.6'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Hi, PopOS has their own support channel. We don't keep track of the changes that derivative projects make, so we don't provide support for them here. The `python3.6` package is included with the default install of Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10. Note that Py3.5 is in 16.04, and that Py3.7 is in 19.04. DO NOT replace the system-provided version of python3 in Ubuntu; doing so will promtply break your system quite horribly.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out most people expect you to install via apt, so finding alternative methods of installing python weren't the easiest so I'll document different methods here

## Method 1

The first method that worked for a friend running the same distro as me (pop_os) was to escape the period in the apt install command

```bsh
sudo apt install python3\.6
```

## Method 2

Second method is installing directly without an installation tool

```bsh
# Install dependancies
$ sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall
$ sudo apt install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

# Retrieve and unzip package
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
$ tar xvf Python-3.6.0.tar.xz

# Make
$ cd Python-3.6.0/
$ ./configure
$ sudo make altinstall
```

If you run into any issue `make`ing, try installing zlib1g via `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: Absolute legend! Thank you for both the commands and the explanations as to why. Method 2 worked wonders for me. If you're using `venv` remember to delete your previous one and recreate it!